# How do I compare data in three tables and get the results that are same?

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql

I have 3 tables A,B,C.

- A has 2 columns d,e
- B has 1 column d
- C has 1 column e

How do I compare these three columns in PostgreSQL? If both column d, e match then update data, else insert data.

Comment: Please post a simple example with a few data and the expected result.

Comment: There are a couple of ways, hard to know which to use without an example. You could run a select query on the tables and join where they match, then update the records that it finds?